# Node.js: halt execution and run async cleanup code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm running async cleanup code by using a custom `exit` event, then calling `process.exit()` after all the cleanup code runs.

However, the rest of the script still executes after I trigger the custom `exit` event. In contrast, when I call `process.exit()`, the rest of the script stops immediately.

For now, I'm just listening for the `exit` event throughout the script and unregistering callbacks. However, this is tedious and error-prone.

Is there a better way to make the rest of the script stop immediately, but still be able to run async cleanup code?

E.g.:

```
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  Promise.race([
    Promise.all(
      process.listeners('beforeExit')
        .map(cb => cb())
        .filter(ret => ret instanceof Promise),
    ),
    pause(5000, new Error('_handleBeforeExit timed out.')),
  ])
    .catch((err) => {
      ErrorLogger.fatal(err, '_handleBeforeExit');
    })
    .then(() => ErrorLogger.shutdown(2000))
    .finally(() => process.exit());
});

...

// Random part of the script
ws.on('msg', () => doSomething);

...

// Another random part
if (!someCondition) {
  process.emit('SIGINT'); // Here, I want doSomething to never run again without having to manually unregister everything
  return;
}
```

Comment: Were you actually planning on providing the script so we can help?

Comment: This is a general Node question, not a debugging question. The script in question is thousands of lines.

Comment: What you've provided should be good enough for someone to help out.